# How to zoom a camera from an arbitrary point in 3d?

Tags: 3d, camera, unity-game-engine, zooming, point

I'm making a interactive map application controlled by multitouch. I want to navigate the map while keeping the places you start the touch under the touch. I use a perspective view and the camera angle down towards the map never changes. I got Moving and Rotating working. Moving by calculating the distance in worldcoordinates (by casting a ray on the base plane) of the current touch and previous touch and moving the camera the same distance and direction. Rotating works by rotating the camera around the touch point.

Now with the zooming I'm having a lot more difficulties. Since when you want to zoom from an arbitrary point on the screen you not only have to move the camera forward, but also towards the touch points. I have an approximation, but it's not very accurate and it doesn't scale well. Is there a way to accurately calculate the camera position so that the point you zoom stays on the same screen coordinates?

I'm using Unity3D (C# for scripting). Here's some example of the code I have.

```
Vector3 prevposition1; // Screen coordinates of previous touch1 
Vector3 nowposition1; // Screen coordinates of touch1 now
Vector3 prevposition2; // Screen coordinates of previous touch2
Vector3 nowposition2; // Screen coordinates of touch2 now
Vector3 prevhitpoint1; // World coordinates of previous touch1 on plane
Vector3 prevhitpoint2; // World coordinates of previous touch2 on plane
Vector3 nowhitpoint1; // World coordinates of touch1 on plane
Vector3 nowhitpoint2; // World coordinates of touch2 on plane

void RotateMap()
{
    transform.RotateAround(nowhitpoint1, Vector3.up, Mathf.Rad2Deg * -(prevAngle - nowAngle));
}

void MoveOverMap()
{
    Vector3 direction = nowhitpoint1 - prevhitpoint1;

    direction = direction * -1f;

    if (prevhitpoint1 != new Vector3(-1,-1,-1))
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + direction;
    } else
    {
        transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
void ZoomMap()
{
    //Calculate direction from center
    RaycastHit hit1;
    int layerMask = 1 << 8;
    Ray ray1 = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay (new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0));
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray1, out hit1, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
    {
    }                         

    //zoom
    Vector3 direction1 = hit1.point - nowhitpoint1;
    float distanceToCentersc1 = Vector2.Distance(nowposition1, new Vector2(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2));
    transform.position = transform.position + (nowDistance - prevDistance) * transform.forward * zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    float distanceToCentersc2 = Vector2.Distance(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(nowhitpoint1), new Vector2(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2));

    //adjust position
    float distanceRatio = distanceToCentersc1/distanceToCentersc2; 
    transform.position = transform.position - direction1 * (1-distanceRatio);
}
```

Comment: Are you working with Android or iOS? You should add the appropriate tag. Also, what Map APIs are you using? Are you using GLES? Do you have any code for us to look at?

Comment: I'm working in Unity. Not using any Map APIs or GLES. I edited my question. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it's helped me understand better. Out of curiosity, are you targeting this code for a Windows 8 machine? Okay. As for the zoom, for a perspective camera, I'd change the field of view, not move the camera closer. Here's an answer that might help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/26815/how-to-zoom-inout-using-the-mouse-wheel.html Let me know if this idea helps you out.

Comment: It's for a Windows 7 machine with a large multitouch screen. If you change the field of view or move the camera in the direction of the camera's forward you succeed in a zoom from the center of the screen. However if you want to keep the world coordinates of your touch under your fingers while moving, it is not enough to just zoom the camera it also has to move to a position. I'm thinking I might need to use linear algebra. Still haven't figured it out.

Comment: if you've translated the camera to the correct position, the fov change will zoom from that position. You can store the position, orientation info. of the camera and use linear algebra to transform it. Unity3d provides convenient functions to do this by the look of things. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you move the camera to the point you want to zoom from, then change the fov, then move the camera back, you have only achieved a zoom from the center. I could use a brute force approach by moving the camera until it reaches the correct point, but its not a good solution to the problem.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure why the behaviour you mention is happening, but it  certainly would be bad. I'll let you know if I find any answers on the subject.

Comment: Thanks! Should I figure it out on my own, I'll post the solution here.